# Which perceived version of each character belongs to who in chapter 39-40 of Dungeon Meshi?

Tags: dungeon-meshi

In chapter 39-40 of *Dungeon Meshi*, the monster can take a form of each party members' perception of the others.

[image]

Take an example for Laius (the first panel), I can guess (from the left):

- The 1st is Senshi's
- The 2nd looking like Farlyn might be Marcille's
- The 3rd is definitely Chilchack's
- The 4th is probably the real one

However, I'm struggling a bit more for the rest. Are there any perceptive readers who have deduced which one belongs to who and why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the series, but your question could use some work; you have left out too many details for me to even understand it, most importantly the title.  I think I have the jist, but I'm not sure.